# Set index values (from Multi index) as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, multi-index

I want to compute an operation that takes a multiindex series like this :

```
bar  one    0
     two    1
baz  one    2
     two    3
```

and transforms it into a DataFrame like this :

```
    one two
bar 0   2
baz 1   3
```

Any idea about how to achieve this easily ? Or at least name this kind of process to make my own searches ?

Comment: it's called `unstack`....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the `unstack`

```
out = s.unstack()
```